# Migration from Spring Boot 2.X to 3.X - removed TypeDef annotation and deprecated EnumType from hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, jvm

I am in the process of migrating the application from Spring Boot 2.X to 3.1.0 and there were problems related to hibernate annotations, which are deprecated/removed in the newer version of spring.
I have the following code and I'm having trouble adapting it to the current version: (I've added these annotations along with the import details to make it clear where they came from.)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo_event", schema = "foo")
@org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef(name = "enum_type", typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType::class)
data class FooEvent(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    var id: Long? = null,

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "event_source")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "enum_type")
    val eventSource: EventSource
)

class PostgreSQLEnumType : org.hibernate.type.EnumType<EventSource>() {
    @Throws(HibernateException::class, SQLException::class)
    override fun nullSafeSet(
        ps: PreparedStatement,
        obj: Any?,
        index: Int,
        session: SharedSessionContractImplementor?
    ) {
        if (obj == null) {
            ps.setNull(index, Types.OTHER)
        } else {
            ps.setObject(index, obj.toString(), Types.OTHER)
        }
    }
}

enum class EventSource {
    SOME_SOURCE, ANOTHER_SOURCE
}
```

I'm wondering how to replace/what workaround to use so as not to change how the code works.

TypeDef has been removed.
Type does not take a "type" argument.
EnumType is deprecated and no longer has a nullSafeSet method. If I wanted to replace this EnumType with jakarta it doesn't let you specify the type.

Looking for a solution so far, it seems to me that the @Convert annotation will work similarly to Type and TypeDef.
Additionally - does it even need the @Type annotation in this case? It seems redundant to me when @Enumerated is already over it.

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "event_source")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "enum_type")
val eventSource: EventSource
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem.
The matter was solved by the library https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils
It provides access to an object with the same function, PostgreSQLEnumType.
Sample solution:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo_event", schema = "foo")
@Convert(attributeName = "enum_type", converter = PostgreSQLEnumType::class)
data class FooEvent(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    var id: Long? = null,

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "event_source")
    val eventSource: EventSource,
)
```